# About Barron's theorem in neural nets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I wanted to clarify my understanding that both the theorems of Barron about approximating functions by neural nets are about one hidden layer net. Is this right?

- Is there any Barron's theorem for high depth neural net?

---

Is there any lecture notes or such which gives a detailed exposition of the Barron's theorem? I only found this, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27883775/wiki/math/pdfs/barron1.pdf